# Jmail vs System.Net.Mail

Tags: .net, email, .net-3.5, system.net.mail, jmail

Currently all our projects use jMail. It has been this way since .NET 1.0.
 
Should I start my next project using System.Net.Mail? 
Are there any advantages that one has over the other or is it just preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, use System.Net.Mail unless jMail offers something that would take a lot of time to implement yourself.

Comment: That's kind of the question. Is there anything useful in jmail that isn't in .NET 2.0? ... I guess not.

Comment: I don't know jMail for .NET. All email requirements in my career as a developer have always been solved with custom code using System.Net.Mail.